# How to increase the height of select box in IE and keep font size same?

Tags: internet-explorer, select, fonts, height

I have run into a problem.

I have a select box with a height of 38px.

It displays correctly on Google Chrome and Firefox... However on IE, its height is lesser than what I mentioned in CSS.

So.. I Googled as usual I found a solution that does the right thing but has its drawback..

The solution for it was mentioned to be increase the font size.

But if I do so.. it looks ugly.

Could you suggest me some other alternatives?

Waiting for your response, please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), which makes your stuff look almost identical on every browser, and then apply the styles.